# Upload an array of Images (each images converted as aFILE) in android

Tags: android, image, file, http-post

I want to upload a number of images say 5. I don't want to convert it as byte array. I want to convert each image as a FILE and add to an array, then send the array to the server. Can anyone help me in this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code and this library add httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar :

String url = "Your Url";

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter(
                CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);


        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

          entity.addPart("fname", new StringBody("xyz"));

        try {

                File file1 = new File("Your image Path");
                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1, "images/jpeg");

                entity.addPart("file", bin1);


                File file2 = new File("Your image Path");
                FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2, "images/jpeg");

                entity.addPart("file", bin2);

                 File file3 = new File("Your image Path");
                FileBody bin3 = new FileBody(file3, "images/jpeg");

                entity.addPart("file", bin3);



            postMethod.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response;
            response = client.execute(postMethod);

            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion Rutvij. But this code is to send a single file i want to send a number of files in a single array...
Something like this entity.addPart("file", bin1[file1, file2, file3]);
is that possible?